# Promtail: combine several files in one label

Tags: nginx, logging, grafana-loki, promtail

On my instance (nginx reverse-proxy) I have several log files, two for each site.
For example:

```
$ ls /var/logs/nginx
site-1.access.log
site-1.error.log
site-2.access.log
site-2.error.log
site-3.access.log           
site-3.error.log
```

For now, I'm able to scrape all logs with the following Promtail config:

```
- job_name: reverseproxy-log
  static_configs:
    - labels:
        __path__: /var/log/nginx/*.log
      targets:
        - localhost
```

This works very well, but the "problem" is that in Grafana/Loki, I can filter only with the filename, for example with the query

```
{filename="/var/log/nginx/site-1.access.log"}
```

I would like to be able to filter first by site, for example, the query `{site="site-1"}` gives me all logs `access` and `error` from `site-1`, and then have the possibility to filter more specifically `access` or `error` logs.

Could you help me to find the correct Promtail config for this?
Thanks